What is the supersonic L/D of subsonic jetliner
Suppose you somehow managed to accelerate a typical jetliner oastbthe sound barrier and to whatever speed you wanted, climbing to keep lift constant. Is there any data on his the L/D evolves with Mach number in this scenario?
